# Adding datasource in weblogic 12c

Tags: java, xml, database, weblogic, datasource

Is there a way to add datasource using xml file in weblogic instead of adding it manually through console.
Something like this:

```
<Resource name="DS_WFMT_DATA" auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.81.34.8:1526:wfmtswvu"
        username="wfmt_data" password="sa1dview"
        maxActive="150" maxIdle="20" maxWait="10000"
        removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="300" logAbandoned="true" />

        <Resource name="DS_DIRECTSTAFFWARE" auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.81.34.8:1526:wfmtswvu"
        username="swpro" password="staffpro1"
        maxActive="150" maxIdle="20" maxWait="10000" logAbandoned="true"/>

        <Resource name="DS_NIMS" auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.75.105.167:1521:nimsc"
        username="nims" password="nims123"
        maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="10000"
        removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="120" logAbandoned="true"/>
```

I know when I add data source, there is an xml file generated in respective domain in path domains\base_domain\config\jdbc but that happens to contain an encrypted password.
 Therefore when I tried to add new  data source using xml file generated from adding datasource manually , that could not be added. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Create a new datasource configuration file in the domains\base_domain\config\jdbc folder with a unique filename in the following format TESTDB-1234-jdbc.xml. Typically MYDS is the datasource name.

Open the TESTDB-1234-jdbc.xml file and edit as per below. (Remember to change the values below to match your setup)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jdbc-data-source xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/jdbc-data-source" xmlns:sec="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security" xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/jdbc-data-source http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/jdbc-data-source/1.2/jdbc-data-source.xsd">
  <name>TESTDB</name>
  <jdbc-driver-params>
    <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:db</url>
    <driver-name>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-name>
    <properties>
      <property>
        <name>user</name>
        <value>user</value>
      </property>
    </properties>
    <password-encrypted></password-encrypted>
      </jdbc-driver-params>
      <jdbc-connection-pool-params>
        <max-capacity>40</max-capacity>
        <connection-creation-retry-frequency-seconds>120</connection-creation-retry-frequency-seconds>
        <test-connections-on-reserve>true</test-connections-on-reserve>
        <test-table-name>SQL SELECT 1 FROM DUAL</test-table-name>
        <init-sql>SQL SELECT 1 FROM DUAL</init-sql>
      </jdbc-connection-pool-params>
    <jdbc-data-source-params>
    <jndi-name>TESTDB</jndi-name>
    <global-transactions-protocol>OnePhaseCommit</global-transactions-protocol>
  </jdbc-data-source-params>
</jdbc-data-source>
```

The created file is missing the encrypted password. You can use the [weblogic.security.Encrypt](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13749/utils.htm#i1209774) utility to encrypt your database password as per below. You will first need to set ensure the Weblogic Environment is setup by going into the domains\base_domain\bin folder and running the following command

```
source ./setDomainEnv.sh
```

You can now go into the domains\base_domain folder and run the [weblogic.security.Encrypt](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13749/utils.htm#i1209774) utility as specifying the database password as follows

```
java weblogic.security.Encrypt dbpassword
```

You must be in the base_domain folder. If you run it in any other folder you will get an exception

> Unable to initialize encryption service, verify you are in the domain directory or have specified the correct value for -Dweblogic.RootDirectory

If you do not want the database password to be visible in your OS history leave it out when running the command and you will be prompted to provide a password. The generated password will be in the following format

> {AES}H8B3Lp73h/9XghMXUmtq5f3CRSpqAzQ0gwoOm5NHYXg=

Copy this value into the password-encrypted tag in your TESTDB-123-jdbc.xml configuration file so the tag now looks like this

```
<password-encrypted>{AES}H8B3Lp73h/9XghMXUmtq5f3CRSpqAzQ0gwoOm5NHYXg=</password-encrypted>
```

You have succesfully created a datasource using xml but now you need to link it to the Weblogic instance. Go to the domains\base_domain\config folder and edit the config.xml file. Add the newly configured jdbc system resource just before the domain tag is closed. Here is a snippet

```
  <jdbc-system-resource>
    <name>TESTDB</name>
    <target>AdminServer</target>
    <descriptor-file-name>jdbc/TESTDB-1234-jdbc.xml</descriptor-file-name>
  </jdbc-system-resource>
```

Remember to use values that apply to your application server. Once done you have successfully linked the data source to the Weblogic Instance however the datasource is not yet active. Restart your weblogic instance for the datasource to be active.
After restarting you can test whether the connection pool is present and active using the Weblogic Admin utility by setting up the Weblogic environment as before and then running the command below

```
java weblogic.Admin -username weblogic -password password -url t3://localhost:port EXISTS_POOL  TESTDB
```

If the connection pool is present and active you will get

> There is already a pool named TESTDB

Otherwise you will get the below exception

> Pool TESTDB does not exist.

You can also do a connection test to the datasource by setting up the Weblogic environment as before and then running the command below

```
java weblogic.Admin -username weblogic -password password -url t3://localhost:port TEST_POOL  TESTDB
```

If the connection is ok you will get

> JDBC Connection Test Succeeded for connection pool "TESTDB".

Remember just because you cannot succesfully test the connection does not mean the datasource was not added to Weblogic. It could be the database is not running so you may need to troubleshoot as appropriate.
Also take note that you could have used the [Weblogic Admin](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/admin_ref/cli21.html#1155747) utility directly as well to create the datasource as well.
When using the Weblogic Admin utility as per above the weblogic password will be visible in your history. 
This is how you create the datasource from an xml file. It is however far easier to just use the Weblogic console.

Comment: Hey, thanks, yes you are right that it is far easier to create a datasource through console. One more question: lets say I create a datasource and correspnding jdbc file is generated. If I give those files to someone else so that he need not add datasources manually. Will that do? Also you can upvote my quetion if you like.

Comment: A better approach is to use a WLST script to create and target your datasource to your domain. Manually updating domain's configuration files is not the recommanded way and is a bit risky.

Comment: Yes you can indeed give the generated file to someone else. They will need to replace the password-encrypted value with the one that they generate on their Weblogic instance. They will also need to link their newly copied and updated datasource file to their Weblogic instance as per the above steps. @EmmanuelCollin is definately correct doing this by had is a bit risky and using WLST script is another good way of doing it.